# Chrome app create

Tags: google-chrome

this is my manifest.json

```
{
    "name" : "www.mysite.com",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "manifest_version" : 1,
    "description" : "Stay Updated with the latest post from www.mysite.com",
    "icons" : {
        "128" : "icon_128.png"
    },

    "browser_action" : {
        "default_icon" : "icon_19.png",
        "popup" : "mysite.html"
    }

}
```

is working..but i upgrade to manifest 2 after is not working..

```
{
    "name" : "www.mysite.com",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "description" : "Stay Updated with the latest post from www.mysite.com",
    "icons" : {
        "128" : "icon_128.png"
    },

    "browser_action" : {
        "default_icon" : "icon_19.png",
        "popup" : "mysite.html"
    }

}
```

can you tell me how to fix this problem ?